# How heavy are you?

Tags: meaning-in-context

I'm studying an English vocabulary book, I found the following question in describing people unit.

> How heavy are you? [English Vocabulary in Use: Elementary](http://www.cambridge.org/us/cambridgeenglish/catalog/grammar-vocabulary-and-pronunciation/english-vocabulary-use-elementary)

While I'm talking with my colleague (who is better than me in English), I asked him: How heavy are you? He smiled, and say: I'm heavy like a car. then He said it is better to say "What is your weight?"

So, Should I avoid using this question?

Comment: Yes, avoid that question. "How much do you weigh?" is better and more common than "What is your weight?", though. The latter is a bit technical-sounding.

Comment: Also, be aware that this is not a question that should be asked lightly of a stranger or casual acquaintance. Asking about someone's weight is a rather personal question.

Comment: How much do you weigh? NOT: what is your weight. What is your weight is ok grammatically or on a doctor's chart, but not in casual conversation.

Comment: I've never stumbled upon "How heavy are you?". The questions: What is your weight? And How much do you weight? Are more common. There are ne more that nobody has mentioned here: What do you weight?

Comment: @SovereignSun Did you mean "weigh"?

Comment: @dasdingonesin Yeh, sorry. My android doesn't want this word.

Comment: What do you weigh? I weigh apples and carrots. What do you weigh? The phrase *What do you weigh?* is ambiguous.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that heavy implies over-weight.

It would be a bit like asking 'How fat are you?'

Better is 'How much do you weigh?' but with caution, as Rob K has suggested.